# Apache-NiFi call jar file from python script

Tags: python, jar, apache-nifi

I have an ExecuteScript processor which calls a Python script to transform the data flow. This works well, but I need to call a jar file and get the results on one piece of data. I've found the following code, but this doesn't work as I can't import subprocess in Jython. Is there another library that can be called, or alternate code which will work? Trying to find a Jython for NiFi scripting guide appears to be a fruitless query.

...`command = "java -jar <filename.jar> <args>" result = suprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()`

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you call Python code in one processor and call Java code in another processor? I haven't understand your challenge in details.

Comment: Did you try `ExecuteStreamCommand ` processor?

Comment: The java jar is run against a field parsed out in the Python code and I need the result to further process within the Python script.

Answer (score 0):

This does work, my error was further below when trying to read the result. NiFi errors are not always easy to decipher and rarely fall on the line of code where the error actually exists.

When reading the results if you wish to convert to string use this code.

...`value = result[0].decode("utf-8")`

Of course substitute appropriate index as needed.